# why there is error with spaces (" ") in arrays?

Tags: java

I tried to split text with spaces (" ") to do "find and replace" method but every time to program reaches a space it stops.

Any idea what's the problem in the following code?

```
static String HTMLchange(String src) {
    String[] arr = src.split("");
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0, i1 = 1, i2 = 2; i < arr.length; i++, i1++, i2++) {
        if (i1 == arr.length) {
            i1 = 0;
        }
        if (i2 == arr.length) {
            i2 = 0;
        }
        if (arr[i].equals("b") && arr[i1].equals("e") && arr[i2].equals("r")) {
            arr[i] = "v";
            arr[i1] = "a";
            arr[i2] = "i";
        }
    }

    res = String.join("", arr);

    return res;
}
```

and in the main:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(HTMLchange(in.next()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
static String HTMLchange(String src) {
    return src.replaceAll("ber", "vai");
}
```

which replaces every occurrence of "ber" in the string with "vai"

**UPDATE**

using `in.next()` fetches the next token. Whitespace is considered as a legit delimiter so when the user enters the string "x ber x" the first token is extracted as "x". Using `in.nextLine()` instead will fetch the whole line and provide the required behavior.

Comment: it still stopping when he there is space.

Comment: input: "x ber x". output: "x".'

Comment: You should provide the input, output and expected output

Comment: I'm getting "x vai x" as output...

Comment: replace `in.next()` with `in.nextLine()`: `next()` gets the next token and spaces are considered as delimiters.

Comment: now it works, thanks!

Comment: @alfasin note that `replace` is sufficient here; no need for `replaceAll`.